# How to get a proper, arbitrarily wide, text stroke?

Tags: ios, drawing, core-graphics, cgcontext, core-text

I am trying to obtain an outer glow effect on some text, similar to that of PhotoShop, such as:
[image]

I tried using both:

```
    CGContextSetTextDrawingMode(context, kCGTextStroke);        
    CGContextShowTextAtPoint(context, x, y, "M", 1);
```

and the CoreText API's to draw attributed strings with a stroke width, (by first drawing the widest, stroke only, all the way to finally only filling the string) with:

```
    CTLineRef line = CTLineCreateWithAttributedString((CFAttributedStringRef)CFBridgingRetain(stringToDraw));
    CGContextSetAlpha(context, myAlpha);
    CGContextSetTextPosition(context, x, y);
    CTLineDraw(line, context);
```

Both solutions work fine, until i try to draw them with a stroke width wider than a certain threshold, then weird artifacts starts showing up.
These pics show the results from setting the draw mode to kCGTextFillStroke and having a white stroke color with an alpha of 0.5 (and increasing the line width for each screenshot):

[image] [image] [image]

The following pics show instead what actually happens when i draw using attributed strings and have the  proper fading effect of the stroke (increasing the strokewidth attribute for each screenshot):

[image] [image] [image]

It looks like a faulty implementation of the stroke algorithm to me, but maybe some of you will know better, does anyone have any idea of how I could get this effect for wider strokes, without having weirdly horned letters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The spikes seems to be caused by the LineCapStyle. Try different settings

Comment: Yea I eventually got to that solution too, and that was indeed the cause of the spikes. Using kCGLineJoinRound instead yields much better results, even if not yet exactly what i would like.

Comment: it would be helpful for future readers (and me!) to get a more thorough code outline of the accepted solution - documentation and examples on core graphics are LIGHT, but this problem exists in NSAttributedString's stroke stuff, too, and is unconfigurable from what I can tell.

Comment: His question was not about NSAttributedString. This is then another question. How to set the LineCapStyle is well documented, one has to just read the docu / API. Fell free to edit the answer and add the line that sets the LineCapStyle. Most readers should be capable to find out the correct chapter of Quart2D docu

Answer (score 0):

Here as i Find a good demo related to [Glowing Text.](https://github.com/andrewgleave/TextGlowDemo)As There are many ways to do this, with numbers of technique quality. One way would be to subclass `UILabel`, and implement some kind of gradient effect in `coregraphics` in the `drawRect` method. as another [good example of Custom gradient UILabel](http://www.vigorouscoding.com/2012/02/custom-gradient-uilabel-with-an-outline/#comment-130)